# How to parse a string that uses individual delimiters into a hierarchical structure using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hierarchical-data

Is there a JavaScript library out there or a pattern/good-practice that can be used to parse a string into a hierarchical data structure, considering that the string uses delimiters to denote levels (very much like, for example, markdown headers)?

```
# H1
## H2
### H3
#### H4
```

So, if I have this string:

```
'#H1 ##H1.1 ##H1.2 #H2 #H2.1 #H3 #H4 ##H4.1 ###H4.1.1 ###H4.1.2 ###H4.1.3 ####H4.1.3.1 ###4.1.4'
```

I'd like it transformed into (the specific structure is not very important. Could be JSON or whatever):

```
H1
    H1.1
    H1.2
H2
    H2.1
H3
H4
    H4.1
        H4.1.1
        H4.1.2
        H4.1.3
            H4.1.3.1
        H4.1.4
```

Of course, there are many ways one can accomplish this and it is not hard at all to do (in fact, I wrote a quick implementation using `split`, and iterating over the array of tokens, counting the empty ones to determine the levels). But I thought this must have been solved already and maybe there is a solution out there readily available and more elegant and efficient than mine. Perhaps a regex wizard can do it in one line?

Comment: [Now you have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) Just because you *can* solve a problem with regex doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: Maybe you want something like https://pegjs.org/

Comment: Combined with https://github.com/shamansir/mdown-parse-pegjs/blob/master/markdown.pegjs even (at least the relevant bits). Although this is a fairly specialized structure, and it's probably easier to just split and count hashes :/

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't come up with pure regex, but does this count as a one-liner.

```js
const string = '#H1 ##H1.1 ##H1.2 #H2 ##H2.1 #H3 #H4 ##H4.1 ###H4.1.1 ###H4.1.2 ###H4.1.3 ####H4.1.3.1 ###H4.1.4',
output = string.replace(/ #/g, '\n').replace(/#/g, '\t').trim()
console.log(output)
```

Comment: For the OP's purposes, this is no better,  it's still just a string. OP wants some hierarchical data, AFAICT, not just transforming to another string.

Comment: Oh doesn't tab/new-lines separated count as hierarchical too? I thought this would work since OP showed this as a sample output, my bad.

Comment: It's hierarchical before, too. OP states a hierarchical *data structure*, not just another string with different chars representing depth.